# É possivel reutilizar os paramêtros de uma Query no JPA?

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

Olá,

Tenho uma dúvida referente aos `Parameters` do objeto `Query` no `JPA`.

Estou implementando paginação das minhas tabelas utilizando o `Primefaces` com `LazyDataModel` e na função que utilizo para efetuar a paginação eu faço 2 buscas na base de dados. A primeira para filtrar os dados e retornar somente os do range q preciso. E a segunda para retornar o `COUNT` do total de registros para o filtro (sem o limite do range).

A unica diferença entre essas queries é que a primeira tem um `maxResults = range[1] - range[0]` e um `firstResult = range[0]`. O efetivamente retornando somente os resultados que quero da base.

Logo, eu gostaria de poder reutilizar os parâmetros de filtro da primeira `Query`, na segunda.

Algo tipo assim:

```
Query queryUm  = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM...")
                .setParameter("x", 1)
                .setParameter("x", 1)
                .setParameter("x", 1)
                .setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0])
                .setFirstResult(range[0]);

List<Entidade> list = queryUm.getResultList();

Query queryDois = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(x) From...");

//reutiliza os parametros aqui..
queryDois.getParameters().addAll(queryUm.getParameters());

Long totalRecords = queryDois.getSingleResult();
```

Já tentei fazer algo assim.. porém a segunda `Query` não executa com um erro dizendo que o parâmetro esperado não foi encontrado.

Aguardo suas contribuições, Obrigado.

Comment: Só uma indagação voltada a performance da sua aplicação: será que não seria mais eficiente realizar uma leitura do tamanho da `List` que foi retornada na primeira query?

Comment: Realmente seria mais 'eficiente', porém não é o valor que eu desejo.
Veja, a primeira Query retorna apenas os valores para paginação da tabela (no max 10 por página), então eu iria ficar com um size de 10 para minha tabela em todos os momentos, quebrando a paginação.

Um jeito que eu poderia fazer seria buscar todas os resultados da base e remover apenas do range que eu necessito, porém como estou lidando com uma tabela com muitos registros e pesada (mtas colunas) preferi fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após investigar um pouco mais para compreender o funcionamento da `Query` e como este Objeto gerencia os parâmetros, identifiquei que ao montar o `JPQL` e criar a instância do objeto, é armazenado no `Set<Parameter<?>>` as referências dos parâmetros que estão na query (ex: `where x = :valorX`) o parâmetro é adicionado no Set antes mesmo de receber o valor à partir do método `setParameter()` da `Query`. E a API também expõe o método `getParameterValue()` que pode receber um `Parameter<?>` como parâmetro e retorna o valor que foi setado na para ser enviado na query.

De qualquer forma, eu posso reutilizar os parâmetros de uma `Query` da seguinte forma:

```
//Cria primeira query
Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT ...")
           .setParameter('a', 1)
           .setParameter('b', 2)
           ...;

List<Entity> resultado = q1.getResultList();

//Cria segunda query
Query q2 = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o)...");

for(Parameter<?> p : q1.getParameters()) {
    //Pega o nome e valor do parâmetro na query anterior e seta na nova..
    q2.setParameter(p.getName, q1.getParameterValue(p));
}
```

Enfim, não é tão bonito quanto gostaria, podendo simplesmente pegar e jogar o `Set<Parameter<?>>` de uma para outra.. mas funciona.

Espero que ajude alguém que passe pela mesma dificuldade.

Answer (score 0):

Não, cada `Query` deve conter seu próprio parâmetro.Pois cada `Query` é executada de maneira independente da outra, e por isso, não se reutiliza o parâmetro de uma na outra.

Mas você pode usar uma variável `param` (nome sugestivo) para passar como o valor do parâmetro caso ele se repita na sua outra `Query`.

Dá uma olhada [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661123/how-do-i-reuse-a-parameter-witha-spring-data-jpa-repository) para ver se funciona para você.

Comment: O post não foi de grande ajuda, eu compreendo como criar uma query e usar/setar parâmetros. O caso é que como ambas vão utilizar os mesmos parâmetros imaginei que poderia existir uma maneira mais simples do que ter que duplicar a lógica para setar os parâmetros (dinâmicos) em ambas as queries. A ideia era justamente pegar os parâmetros de uma e jogar pra outra reutilizar. Seria uma boa a API possibilitar essa funcionalidade.